# TrainImagesClassifier (SVM) fails when executed from within QGIS modeler

Tags: qgis, classification, qgis-modeler, orfeo-toolbox

I made a small model in QGIS that runs Second Order Image Statistics, the SVM Trainer, and Image Classification, all tools from the Orfeo provider.

The problem is it fails everytime. When I run the tools outside the modeler, using the processing toolbox (not the command line), they run perfectly, but when I put them in the modeler, they fail. More specifically, the trainer does not export the model nor the confusion matrix, which causes the next step, Image Classification to fail.

Is this a problem that has been encountered before? Does anybody have a suggestion on how to solve this?

Update: Below is the log output when the model atempts to execute the Trainer.

```
2016 May 19 13:47:03 : Application.logger (DEBUG) Entering DoExecute 
2016 May 19 13:47:03 : Application.logger (INFO) Elevation management: setting default height above ellipsoid to 0 meters
2016 May 19 13:47:05 : Application.logger (INFO) Number of training samples: 1125 
2016 May 19 13:47:05 : Application.logger (INFO) Size of training set: 1125 
2016 May 19 13:47:05 : Application.logger (INFO) Size of validation set: 1058 
2016 May 19 13:47:05 : Application.logger (INFO) Size of labeled training set: 1125 
2016 May 19 13:47:05 : Application.logger (INFO) Size of labeled validation set: 1058 
CvSVM::RBF = 2 
CvSVM::C_SVC = 100 
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (There is only a single class) in cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses, file C:\OSGeo4W64\usr\src\osgeo4w\opencv\opencv-2.4.11\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp, line 729 
2016 May 19 13:47:05 : Application.logger (FATAL) The following error occurred during application execution : C:\OSGeo4W64\usr\src\osgeo4w\opencv\opencv-2.4.11\modules\ml\src\inner_functions.cpp:729: error: (-5) There is only a single class in function cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that OTB was not able to read samples class in the input polygons

Labels should be in the shapefile in a column attribute. By default OTB is looking for a column name 'Class' but you can change this value in the SVM trainer application.